# С помощью какого API можно сделать поиск картинок и загрузить их на сервер?

Tags: php, парсер, изображения, поиск-api

Задался вопросом, как возможно реализовать подобный парсер картинок с загрузкой на сервер, с помощью какого api это реально сделать, продукции около 3000 и по каждой единицы необходимо 3 фото. Если у кого-нибудь есть идеи, прошу подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

У яндекса, на сколько знаю, нет api картинок. Google предоставляет платную версию или устаревший api с возможностью получения 8 изображений на запрос. Я бы посоветовал попробовать Bing. У них бесплатные запросы (с лимитом конечно), но качество хуже гугла, конечно.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, если у бинга тоже лимит на ограничение, тогда  я думаю будет лучше использовать google-api, Вот только, правда ли, что yandex api не поддерживает поиск картинок по запросу, сейчас  приступлю к чтению документации yandex api.